# Binding energy of the nucleus

Tags: homework-and-exercises, nuclear-physics, mass-energy, binding-energy

In a reaction U235+1n->141 Ba +92Kr +(3) 1n+200MeV, the energy released (200Mev) is of one atom or of 6.023*10^23 atoms?

Comment: note that 200 MeV is around $10^{-23}$ kilotons of TNT (not a coincidence that the kT is the preferred unit of these devices, I mean with the 23 in the exponent and all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The energy is released by a single atom. One mole of atoms would release an energy of

$200*6.023*10^{23} eV =200*1.6*6.023*10^{4}J $

Comment: Meaning if i multiple it with 6.023*10^23 then i will get the energy released by 1 mole atoms?

Comment: Yes. And if you want the energy in Joules, then multiply by $1.6*10^{-19}$